# Use of curly brackets in conditional statement causes slightly lower performance

Tags: c++, linux, performance

**Introduction**

I am working on a coding practice question where people post their execution time to see who achieves the best performance. I wrote a recursive function for calculating the modular exponentiation of large (3 digits) numbers.

**What is the problem?**

I realized that when I don't use curly brackets I am getting a faster execution time. I kept testing this finding multiple times and I consistently got the same result.

**Code 1**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int modExp(int a, int b, int c){
    if(b==0)
        return 1;
    return (a*modExp(a,b-1,c))%c;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 450;
    int B = 768;
    int C = 517;

    int result = modExp(A,B,C);
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Execution time of code 1**

[image]

**Code 2**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int modExp(int a, int b, int c){
    if(b==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return (a*modExp(a,b-1,c))%c;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 450;
    int B = 768;
    int C = 517;

    int result = modExp(A,B,C);
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Execution time of code 2**

[image]

**What I think is going on:**

Although once the execution times are expressed in 3 significant digits it appears that Code 1 is twice as much faster than Code 2, I think this is just a rounding issue. The execution time is probably something like 0.001465s without the curly brackets and when I use the curly brackets, it is causing enough delay to cause the execution time to be rounded up to 0.002s.

Is it possible to increase the significant digits of the execution time?
Am I right with my hypothesis? Why do you think the delay is caused?

Comment: Any modern C++ compiler will generate identical code, for both versions. They are logically equivalent. This is line noise.

Comment: You cannot use a single run as a comparison of performance.  You need to run this function thousands/millions of times and get an average.  There is a [nice online tool](http://quick-bench.com/) you can use to do this.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? What compiler options are you using?

Comment: Compare the assembly code for both. They'll be identical.

Comment: Assembly of both versions: @ [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/FEbIlL)
They are exactly the same

Comment: when you measure an observable only once your variance is pratically infinite, ie you cannot make any conclusions from the measured value. Repeat and average. And turn on optimizations

Comment: @TedLyngmo Put them both in the same file (rename one obviously) and turn on -O2. You might see something neat.

Comment: @user4581301 Like this? [both in one file](https://godbolt.org/z/TWCihk) I didn't see any difference. If I misunderstood, can you provide a link and explain what to look for?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Interesting. I was expecting something more like https://godbolt.org/z/ivPcck And to be honest even that's kinda stupid. You'd think the compiler could completely fold them together, use the same function for both names, and save the jump.

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing statistical noise from a single run of the executables. Both executables will be identical for this input (the compiler understands that they are logically equivalent and produce output accordingly), and if you run them thousands or millions of times and take an average, you'll see the same execution time.

It's true that sometimes subtle differences in syntax can have subtly different semantics, and thus end up performing differently, but use of optional scope braces is not one of those cases.